# How do I disable magic_quotes_runtime in PHP 5.5?

Tags: php

I'm trying to migrate a script in php 5.2 to 5.5 that uses [set_magic_quotes_runtime()](http://php.net/set-magic-quotes-runtime) to disable them. I found a hint that suggested I could replace it with:

```
ini_set ("magic_quotes_runtime", 0);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: This is deprecated since 5.3 so I imagine it is totally removed from 5.5?

Comment: Could be. But maybe not: magic quotes are best forgotten. What is the exact problem you're trying to address?

Comment: I made an edit, based on what your code implied, that turns the question into "how to disable"; if this wasn't the intent of your question, speak up and the edit can be rolled back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply delete the line.

Magic quotes have been dead for some time, and have been removed in PHP 5.4 and later.  There is no reason to force them to off when they don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to turn them off, there's nothing to be done - [the feature has been removed from PHP entirely since PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php). There's no need for the line you cited at all in PHP 5.5.

If you are trying to turn them on, you would need to recreate the feature in userland using something like str_replace(); however, I would urge you not to do it.